# Inequality proof with cos

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove for any $x_1$ and $x_2$, $|\cos{x_2}-\cos{x_1}| \leq |x_2-x_1|$.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the mean value theorem. For each $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R$, there exists $\phi(x_1,x_2) $ which lies between $x_1,x_2$ such that:
$$\dfrac{\cos x_1-\cos x_2}{x_2-x_1}=\cos'(\phi(x_1,x_2))=-\sin(\phi(x_1,x_2))\Rightarrow$$ 
$$|\cos x_1-\cos x_2|=|\sin(\phi(x_1,x_2))|\cdot|x_1-x_2|\leq|x_1-x_2|$$

Comment: can you just explain what the $\phi$ represents?

Comment: The mean value theorem states that there exists $\phi \in (a,b)$ such that $$\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}=f'(\phi)$$ . This happens for given $a,b$ . 

In general, though, the number $\phi\in(a,b)$ depends on $a,b$. So we can write $\phi (a,b)$

Comment: but it is when x_1 and x_2 are close together but in general we must proof it

Answer (score 0):

$\left|\cos(x)-\cos(y)\right| = \left|\left(\cos y +\int_y^x \cos '(t) dt\right)-\cos ( x )\right|=\left|\int_y^x \cos '(t) dt\right|\le \left|\int_y^x -\sin(t) dt\right| \le \left|\int_y^x \left|-\sin(t)\right|\right| dt \le \left(\sup\left|-\sin\right|\right)\left|\int_y^x dt\right| \le \left|\int_y^x dt\right| = |x-y|$